# Determine when iPhone is on its back

Tags: objective-c

Is there anyway to determine when the iPhone is on its back?

This is on a surface or the user is holding it in hands and just shifts the phone so its laying flat in mid-air.

I know that the iPhone has a gyro and accelerometer but am not sure how they can be used to find this out.

Comment: Look at `UIDevice orientation`.

Comment: If you decide to go with the accelerometer take a look at the values (and a sign) of the z-axis. You might want to compile and run (on device) some sample code like [this one](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/basic-sensors-in/9781449309480/ch04.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [UIDeviceOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDeviceOrientation):

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIDeviceOrientation) {
    UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
    UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,            // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
    UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,  // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,       // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,      // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,              // Device oriented flat, face up
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown             // Device oriented flat, face down
};
```